# How to modify merge sort to just return the index of element without sorting?

Tags: algorithm, recursion

How to get the index of certain element recursively without sorting the array?

Comment: What do you want to achive? Only find a certain element? Maybe it's better so search the element iterativ...

Comment: It's hard to understand the relation between sorting and finding an element in an array in your question. If you sort the array, the elements will in general be in different places, so it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: recursively ???

Answer (score 0):

A brute force search and recursive search both has same time complexity in this case. But still if you want the recursive version then pseudo code would:

1. call a function with array and key to search.Init a static index for array.
2. check if index is out of bounds then return -1 ( meaning not found)
3. check if current element in array is key.
   if true return the static index;
4. else return function call by incrementing the index.

Answer (score 0):

The question probably refers to finding the rank of a certain element in the sorted list.

Indeed, this operation does not require explicitly sorting the array, but simply counting how many elements are smaller than it (assuming ascending sort).

The best possible complexity for this is O(n), because each element needs to be checked.

It is straightforward to achieve O(n) complexity using a non-recursive approach -- simply iterate through all elements, and increase a counter every time a smaller element is encountered. The final value of the counter denotes the position of the element of interest in the sorted array (note that this was obtained without explicitly sorting).

A simple recursive solution which would mimic this behavior is illustrated below (using c-style code):

```
getRank(int value, int* array, int nElements) {
    if (nElements == 0) return 0;

    if (array[0] < value)
        return 1 + getRank(value, array + 1, nElements - 1);
    else
        return getRank(value, array + 1, nElements - 1);
}
```